# iOS UItableviewCell clear old cell values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

First of all sorry for asking this as I know there are a lot of questions which are similar to this. But so far nothing has worked for me. I have a table view with two buttons. On click of the button it loads two different custom cells. But I can't seem to clear out the old cell values no matter what I try. I have tried the prepareForReuse method to clear the old views but I end up with nothing displaying on the cells.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if([[self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count] > 0)
        {
            id object = [[self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            if (indexPath.section == self.sections.count-1)
            {
                if(self.CategoryButtonType == 0)
                {
                    MediaListCarousel * cell = [self getMediaCellCarousel:object];
                        return cell;
                }
                else
                {
                     NonMediaTableViewCell * cell = [self getNonMediaCell:object];
                      return cell;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                 //Do other stuff
            }
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

Here are the custom cells

```
-(NonMediaTableViewCell *)getNonMediaCell:(NSString *)name
{
    NonMediaTableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nonmediaCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (NonMediaTableViewCell*)[VFHelper findCellWithClassName:[NonMediaTableViewCell class] nibName:@"NonMediaTableViewCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    [cell setNonMediaWithPackageName:name
                                         delegate:self];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}


-(MediaListCarousel *)getMediaCellCarousel:(NSString *)name
{
    MediaListCarousel * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:mediaCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (MediaListCarousel*)[VFHelper findCellWithClassName:[MediaListCarousel class] nibName:@"MediaListCarousel"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    [cell setUp:name delegate:self];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

each of those custom cell has the prepareForReuse method as defined below.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    // Clear contentView
    BOOL hasContentView = [self.subviews containsObject:self.contentView];
    if (hasContentView) {
        for(UIView *subview in [self.contentView subviews])
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

What happening when i add the removeFromSuperview in the prepareForReuse method I can empty view when I switch between the two views. If i dont use the prepareForReuse to remove the view I end up with views on top of each other when I click the different button. Can some one please help with this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT TO SHOW CUSTOM CELL CODE

```
-(void) getNonMediaCell:(NSString *)package
                                      delegate:(NSObject <nonMediaCellDelegate> *)delegate
{
    self.package = package;
    [self loadValuefFromDB];
    self.addonName = addonName;

    _delegate = delegate;
    [self.btnSeemore addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSeemoreClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    if(_addons.isHidden)
    {
        _planDescTextView.hidden = YES;
        _heightConstraintforPlanDescView.constant = 0;
        _btnSeemore.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
    else
    {
        _planDescTextView.text = description;
        CGSize neededSize = [_planDescTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(_planDescTextView.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
        _planDescTextView.hidden = NO;
        _heightConstraintforPlanDescView.constant = neededSize.height + 5;
        _btnSeemore.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
        _btnSeemore.imageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
        _btnSeemore.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    }

    if(IsEmpty(addons.state))
    {
        _UIViewEntitlement.hidden = YES;
        _UIViewBtnRepurchase.hidden = YES;
        _seperatorView.hidden = YES;
        [self resetCell];
        [self setPriceLabelValue];
        [self.purchaseBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.purchaseBtn.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_Purcahse", addonName];
        self.purchaseBtn.accessibilityValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_Purcahse", addonName];
        self.purchaseBtn.accessibilityIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_Purcahse", addonName];
        self.recurringIndicatorImageView.hidden = NO;
        [self addOnRecurringIndicatorImages];
    }
    else
    {
        _UIViewEntitlement.hidden = NO;
        UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 20)];
        VFAddonPlanentitlementCell * cell = (VFAddonPlanentitlementCell*)[VFHelper findCellWithClassName:[VFAddonPlanentitlementCell class] nibName:@"VFAddonPlanentitlementCell"];
        [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 20)];

        if(!IsEmpty(_addons.remainingDays))
        {
            if(recurring || allowCancel)
            {
                if([[_addons.state uppercaseString] isEqualToString:@"ONHOLD"])
                {
                    [cell setDaysRemainingColorWithTitleOnHold:@"Renews" daysRemainings:[_addons.remainingDays stringValue]];
                }
                else
                {
                    [cell setRemainingColorWithTitle:@"Renews" daysRemainings:[_addons.remainingDays stringValue]];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                [cell setDaysRemainingColorWithTitle:@"Time left" daysRemainings:[_addons.remainingDays stringValue]];
            }
            [headerView addSubview:cell];
        }
        [_UIViewEntitlement addSubview:headerView];
    }
}
```

Comment: do not remove views, instead try setting proper values in fields, like set empty string in labels, textfields etc. if you can show the cell class, let's see what to update.

Comment: I am sure that in setup you are adding subviews. Don't do that. Don't add and remove views. Add them in XIB/PrototypeCell give there reference and change their properties. Because cells are reused. So the views if you keep on adding would be added on top of other.

Comment: you are creating `UIView *headerView` here. try adding this using interface builder and use hide/show depends on conditions

Comment: The UIView *headerView can have multiple view inside it or none. Not sure how I can use the XIB to control that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
-(void) getNonMediaCell:(NSString *)package
                                      delegate:(NSObject <nonMediaCellDelegate> *)delegate
{
    .....//other code
    UIView *headerView = [_UIViewEntitlement viewWithTag:12345];
    if(headerView == nil) {
        headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 20)];
        [headerView setTag:12345];//set tag
    } else {
         NSLog(@"headerView already exist");
    }
    //set values
    .....//other code
}
```

and in reuse method

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    UIView *header = [_UIViewEntitlement viewWithTag:12345];//use same tag
    [header removeFromSuperview];
}
```

if you are creating and adding multiple views programatically, then set tag to each views and remove those in reuse by accessing it with same tag value.

Comment: I just tried it but it didnt seem to work :( Have checked that I have added all the tags correctly but when I switch view the old cell is still visible

Comment: is `headerView ` is the only one you are creating programatically?

Comment: Inside the headerView I am creating a VFAddonPlanentitlementCell . Do I need to add a tag to that and remove that as well? my understanding was  removing the headerView would remove that as well

Comment: yes, it will remove subviews too. are you adding headerview from anywhere else?

Comment: add a check before creating new header instances. also check for the NSLog added. updated the answer.